# git apparently keeps saying that a file has been modified when it has not

Tags: git, repository, line-endings

I am experiencing a curious situation,
probably related to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778862/how-does-git-detect-that-a-file-has-been-modified),
but I'd like to better understand what is going on here.

I have a repository where right after a clone
`git status` reports that a file has been modified.

I created a minimal reproduction [here](https://github.com/DanySK/git-gradlew.bat-anomaly),
with a repo containing just the ignore list, a very trivial `.gitattributes`,
and the file causing me headaches: `gradlew.bat`.

All my attempts in the following are performed using Linux/ZSH (the issue has been reproduced on multiple Linux installations and shells).

Right after clone, if I run `git status`, I get:

```
❯ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   gradlew.bat

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And if I try to check out the unmodified version with `git checkout HEAD -- gradlew.bat`, then issue `git status` again:

```
❯ git checkout HEAD -- gradlew.bat
❯ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   gradlew.bat

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Okay then, I downloaded [the file directly from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanySK/git-gradlew.bat-anomaly/master/gradlew.bat), and checked the hashes:

```
❯ md5sum gradlew.bat
6b56324406b764fd6c5d4d7d215a3cd7  gradlew.bat
❯ sha512sum gradlew.bat
d4fef021e30640670fe20243e4fc4f0336b2f118f8c172c138a8c0c3028c93b12da9479812cede4196401bbc87ce9df89573dbec7378373cafafca6698867f55  gradlew.bat
```

Which are exactly the same of the file `git` mark as changed:

```
❯ md5sum gradlew.bat && sha512sum gradlew.bat
6b56324406b764fd6c5d4d7d215a3cd7  gradlew.bat
d4fef021e30640670fe20243e4fc4f0336b2f118f8c172c138a8c0c3028c93b12da9479812cede4196401bbc87ce9df89573dbec7378373cafafca6698867f55  gradlew.bat
```

This means it's not even matter of `LF`/`CRLF` line endings.

`git diff` is not helpful either, as it just suggests that the file changed entirely:

```
diff --git a/gradlew.bat b/gradlew.bat
index ac1b06f..107acd3 100755
--- a/gradlew.bat
+++ b/gradlew.bat
@@ -1,89 +1,89 @@
-@rem
-@rem Copyright 2015 the original author or authors.
-@rem
-@rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
-@rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
-@rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
-@rem
-@rem      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
-@rem
-@rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
-@rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
-@rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
-@rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
-@rem limitations under the License.
-@rem
-
-@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
-@rem ##########################################################################
-@rem
-@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
-@rem
-@rem ##########################################################################
-
-@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
-if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal
-
-set DIRNAME=%~dp0
-if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
-set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
-set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%
-
-@rem Resolve any "." and ".." in APP_HOME to make it shorter.
-for %%i in ("%APP_HOME%") do set APP_HOME=%%~fi
-
-@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
-set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx64m" "-Xms64m"
-
-@rem Find java.exe
-if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome
-
-set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
-%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
-if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto execute
-
-echo.
-echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
-echo.
-echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
-echo location of your Java installation.
-
-goto fail
-
-:findJavaFromJavaHome
-set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
-set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe
-
-if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto execute
-
-echo.
-echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
-echo.
-echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
-echo location of your Java installation.
-
-goto fail
-
-:execute
-@rem Setup the command line
-
-set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
-
-
-@rem Execute Gradle
-"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %*
-
-:end
-@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
-if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd
-
-:fail
-rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
-rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
-if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
-exit /b 1
-
-:mainEnd
-if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal
-
-:omega
+@rem
+@rem Copyright 2015 the original author or authors.
+@rem
+@rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
+@rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
+@rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
+@rem
+@rem      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
+@rem
+@rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
+@rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
+@rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
+@rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
+@rem limitations under the License.
+@rem
+
+@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
+@rem ##########################################################################
+@rem
+@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
+@rem
+@rem ##########################################################################
+
+@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
+if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal
+
+set DIRNAME=%~dp0
+if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
+set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
+set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%
+
+@rem Resolve any "." and ".." in APP_HOME to make it shorter.
+for %%i in ("%APP_HOME%") do set APP_HOME=%%~fi
+
+@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
+set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx64m" "-Xms64m"
+
+@rem Find java.exe
+if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome
+
+set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
+%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
+if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto execute
+
+echo.
+echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
+echo.
+echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
+echo location of your Java installation.
+
+goto fail
+
+:findJavaFromJavaHome
+set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
+set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe
+
+if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto execute
+
+echo.
+echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
+echo.
+echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
+echo location of your Java installation.
+
+goto fail
+
+:execute
+@rem Setup the command line
+
+set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
+
+
+@rem Execute Gradle
+"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %*
+
+:end
+@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
+if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd
+
+:fail
+rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
+rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
+if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
+exit /b 1
+
+:mainEnd
+if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal
+
+:omega
```

The next I could think of was permissions, but the file was `-rwxr-xr-x` and remains `-rwxr-xr-x`.

I tried to see if there's anything else via `stat`, but I found no clue there either:

```
❯ git reset --hard HEAD && stat gradlew.bat && git status && stat gradlew.bat
HEAD is now at f6d1022 remove irrelevant stuff
  File: gradlew.bat
  Size: 2763            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 7342244     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  <redacted>)   Gid: ( 1000/  <redacted>)
Access: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
Modify: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
Change: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
 Birth: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   gradlew.bat

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
  File: gradlew.bat
  Size: 2763            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 7342244     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  <redacted>)   Gid: ( 1000/  <redacted>)
Access: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
Modify: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
Change: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
 Birth: 2022-07-05 14:48:48.314141714 +0200
```

I'm now out of ideas, what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This means it's not even matter of LF/CRLF line endings.

Ah, but it is.

[Your repository is clone-able](https://github.com/DanySK/git-gradlew.bat-anomaly/), so I cloned it.  Here's what's actually in the file:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD:gradlew.bat
ac1b06f93825db68fb0c0b5150917f340eaa5d02
$ git cat-file -p ac1b06f93825db68fb0c0b5150917f340eaa5d02 | head -3 | vis
@rem\^M
@rem Copyright 2015 the original author or authors.\^M
@rem\^M
```

The `vis` command shows what's in the file, making sure that control characters like carriage return (control-M) are visible as backslash, hat, letter-code.  We see that the file actually has CRLF endings as stored *in the repository*.  This copy of the file *literally cannot be changed*, because it's inside a commit, and no part of any commit can ever be changed.

Curiously, we find the following `.gitattributes` file:

```
$ vis .gitattributes
* text=auto eol=lf
*.[cC][mM][dD] text eol=crlf
*.[bB][aA][tT] text eol=crlf
*.[pP][sS]1 text eol=crlf
```

Now, the interesting thing about a `.gitattributes` like this is that it *tells Git to mess with file data*.  The tricky part is *how* Git will go about doing this messing-with-file-data:

- Git will, on *copying the file out* of a Git commit or other internal frozen-format version (e.g., extracting from commit or index to working tree), do LF-only to CRLF editing if / as directed;
- Git will, on *copying the file from the working tree to compress it and store it in the repository* (in the index or eventually in a commit), do CRLF to LF-only editing if/as directed.

The "as directed" part is complex and is determined by the rules in the `.gitattributes`, but yours add up to saying that for `*.bat` files, Git *should* do the operation *in both cases*.  So it does:

- On the way out, any LF-only line endings that are present become CRLF endings.
- On the way in, any CRLF line endings become LF-only endings.

Since the file *as committed* has CRLF endings, nothing happens "on the way out", but *should you put the file back in*, it *will be changed* to be stored with LF-only line endings.

We can see this in action here.  We start with `git ls-files --eol` to tell us what's actually in the index and working tree, for each file stored in Git's index:

```
$ git ls-files --eol
i/lf    w/lf    attr/text=auto eol=lf   .gitattributes
i/lf    w/lf    attr/text=auto eol=lf   .gitignore
i/crlf  w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      gradlew.bat
```

So we see that the `attr`s applied to `gradlew.bat` are `text eol=crlf`.  The `attr`s applied to the other files are `text=auto eol=lf`.

The *index and working tree copies* of the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` are LF-only.  The *index and working tree copies* of `gradlew.bat` are CRLF (for both).

If we now `git add gradlew.bat`—we may need to use `--renormalize`, depending on Git vintage and certain raw stat data and timings and a lot of other details that vary from one system to another—and then run `git ls-files --eol` again, we see that the *index* version of `gradlew.bat` has changed:

```
$ git ls-files --eol
i/lf    w/lf    attr/text=auto eol=lf   .gitattributes
i/lf    w/lf    attr/text=auto eol=lf   .gitignore
i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      gradlew.bat
```

Committing this version will make a new commit in which the stored-for-all-time copy has LF-only line endings.  Every *extraction* will produce CRLF endings, because `gradlew.bat` has `attr/text eol=crlf` applied, and every `git add` will have those CRLF endings changed back to LF-only.

This whole area of Git's operation is very messy.  If it's possible to *not* have Git mess with line endings, that's always my preference.  However, if some files *must* have CRLF endings, the `.gitattributes` style you've written is my preference here: the files in the *repository* will be LF-only, but the files in your *working tree* will be CRLF files.  You may have to do one `git add --renormalize .` pass to "clean up" and commit so that from then on, Git is happy with things.

Comment: This is a great explanation, **thank you**.
(and yes, the repository is cloneable for reproducibility purposes, so thank you for taking the time to reproduce the behaviour)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but how to fix it in the right way? If we had `i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      gradlew.bat` and after changed `.gitattributes` it becomes `i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text eol=lf       gradlew.bat` with warning `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in gradlew.bat. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory` then is it correct to push this to repo?